# Mongodb- Query to check if a field in the json array exists or not

Tags: mongodb

I have a JSON in MongoDB and I am trying to check if at least one of the items in the JSON doesn't contain a specific field.

```
{
    "_id" : 12345,
     "orderItems" : [ 
        { 
            "itemId" : 45678,
            "isAvailable" : true,
            "isEligible" " false
        },
        {
             "itemId" : 87653,
             "isAvailable" : true
         }
   ]
}
```

So in the above JSON, since the 2nd one under order items doesn't contain `iseligible` field, I need to get this _id.

I tried the below query so far, which didnt work:

```
db.getCollection('orders').find({"orderItems.iseligible":{$exists:false})
```

Comment: can you add the expected output? in JSON?

Comment: If iseligible doesnt exist for any of the items, I need that complete document to be displayed.

For eg., have 2 documents:
{ "_id" : 12345, "orderItems" : [ { "itemId" : 45678, "isAvailable" : true, "isEligible" " false }, { "itemId" : 87653, "isAvailable" : true } ] }
{ "_id" : 12346, "orderItems" : [ { "itemId" : 45678, "isAvailable" : true, "isEligible" " false }, { "itemId" : 87653, "isEligibe": false, "isAvailable" : true } ] }

In the above example, the output should return first document since it doesnt contain isEligible for one of the item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/#mongodb-query-op.-elemMatch) to evaluate the presence of the nested key. Once that's accomplished, project out the `_id` value.

```
db.orders.find({
  orderItems: {
    $elemMatch: {
      "isEligible": {
        $exists: false
      }
    }
  }
},
{
  _id: 1
})
```

Here is a [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/q-ra5JXPwdR) with the finished code, and a [similar SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38506353/8943092).